# Cannot execute PCManFM from the program's menu on Lubuntu 19.04

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, pcmanfm

I recently noticed that when I click on the default file explorer (PCManFM) icon in the program's menu, the program doesn't start.

I ran the system's update to check if the updates would fix the issue, but nothing changed.

I would like to know how can I check which command line is the menu calling, or how can I execute the software from a terminal, just to check if the issue is with the menu link of the software itself.

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Lubuntu 19.04. I could be wrong, but I believe that PCManFM is the default file manager for Lubuntu, and is has worked well since day one up until now.

Comment: In 19.04 Lubuntu uses LxQt for a desktop environment, and the default file manager is PCManFM-Qt. I'm not sure what you mean by "the program's menu" though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "-Qt" at the end. By program's menu I mean start menu or main menu.

Comment: `Exec=pcmanfm-qt %U` is what I see in the .desktop file, *pcmanfm-qt.desktop*. So running just `pcmanfm-qt` in a terminal would provide some hints.

Comment: @DKBose I tried "pcmanfm-qt" but I got nothing back from the terminal. I ended up installing the non qt version of the pcmanfm and I now I have a file manager to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to `/usr/share/applications` (typically) to find the .desktop files and then edit them appropriately with any text editor. If you need to debug I find running the command in a terminal to see any errors helps.